# A message sent to adapter "WCF-WebHttp" on send port "" with URI "https://na59.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/43.0/00Df4000001dsdy" is suspended

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I need help on SalesForce integration with biztalk 2016 environment.

I'm using "WCF-WebHttp" adapter to send request to SalesForce with custom behavior as below and getting below suspended message to FORCE.com.

So, Do i need to add security protocol on my WCF behavior like TLS 1.1, 1.2 to call salesforce API through  BizTalk ?

### EventViewer Error message

> A message sent to adapter "WCF-WebHttp" on send port "DeveloperForce.SendCreateAccount.REST" with URI "https://na59.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/43.0/00Df4000001dsdy" is suspended. 
>    Error details: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'na59.salesforce.com'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace: 
>      at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.RequestCallback(IAsyncResult result) 
>    MessageId:  {345BABC2-0BE9-42F2-8D47-D123A402B3CD}
>    InstanceID: {FEDE9235-18DB-4E3F-969E-6648A869F45A}

Send Port Screen shot:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sales force requires TLS1.1/1.2 for communication. If you don’t have BizTalk 2016 latest CU5 then you need to set the security protocol either in custom service behavior ( a bit more work) or in a custom pipeline component. All you need is to set `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 or Tls12`

Or as per [CU5](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4091110/support-for-tls-1-2-protocol-in-biztalk-server) TLS1.2 support is added.

Comment: Installed CU5 on BizTalk 2016 environment now it's support TLS1.2 but still have suspended message telling "System.Net.WebException: (500) Server Error
 at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.RequestCallback(IAsyncResult result)"

Comment: This looks like a different error, 500 error typically comes from server side. Please check with yr sales force team if they received request or not. You can also use postman tool to test sales force api outside BizTalk to make sure it’s working as expected with the request data you are sending

Comment: I made request “https://na59.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/43.0/00Df4000001dsdy” through SOAPUI and getting response back through force.com.

Comment: I also checked WCF-WebHttp message tab has “Accept: application/xml” value to accept response from force.com.

Comment: You are using a custom behavior, I would suggest to debug there. Use Fiddler as proxy to see request/response. Install fiddler and set proxy on send port as localhost port 8888.

Comment: Great, pleas mark this as answer if it helped u fixing the issue

Comment: successfully create new account entity and I made mistake first time to not using correct address of the REST API endpoint. the correct REST API endpoint is (https://na59.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/sobjects) and we can find available REST API using (curl https://na59.salesforce.com/services/data/).   Thanks @Vikas Bhardwaj

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=EED7B74B84686828!1648&app=OneNote&authkey=!AAjky1vOBJwop2w

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a trust issue. Maybe the certification chain cannot be resolved / isn't trusted. Check this using certmgr.msc.

1. Make sure "DigiCert Global Root CA" is in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store
2. Verify that "DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA" is in the Intermediate Certification Authories store.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @David Abrahamsson’s

Answer (score 0):

have you installed SalesForce certificate? on your Biztalk machine using the biztalk service account?

Comment: Thank you for your response @Hichamveo I also updated project solution file as link.